# How to specify colors in character vector with for loop in r

Tags: r, graphics, for-loop, plot

I have character vector, say v1, with four levels. Cases of the levels are randomly distributed within the vector v1:

```
set.seed(10)

v1<-sample((rep(c("book","Dog","sun","shell"),c(12,30,18,40))))
```

Second character vector, say v2, contains four colors:

```
v2<-palette(rainbow(4))
```

Given that I want to color the cases of each level from v1 with particular color from the v2, I am stacked how I can achieve it using for loop in R.

Here is my code that doesn't work:

```
col.dots<-v1
for(i in 1:length(unique(v1))){
  for(y in 1: length(v2)){
    col.dots[col.dots==unique(v1)[i]]<-v2[y]
  }
}
```

Returned col.dots vector contains only "red" color...

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `palette` doesn't do what you think it does. Second, we can do this just with vector indexing:

```
v2 <- rainbow(4)
> names(v2) <- unique(v1)
> v2[v1]
```

Obviously, `unique(v1)` will return the values in a particular order. You'll have to specify the values manually if you want them assigned differently.

Comment: tnx for the answer! Nice solution. However, do you have solution using for loop, maybe? Regarding palette, I agree it is redundant info in this case and I overlooked it in the post, but I need it in my overall code for plotting.

Comment: @Newbie_R `palette` isn't redundant in your example, it's wrong. `rainbow` returns a vector of four colors. Wrapping that in `palette` does not return a vector of four colors. Maybe your actual code differs from what you put in the question. Of course you could do it with a for loop, but I'm not going to provide a not very good solution without a compelling reason for why you _have_ to use a for loop.

Comment: you are right...I got it wrong... I did `palette("default")`, then `v2<-palette(rainbow(4))`. Returned v2 vector contained eight colors. However, when I applied again `v2<-palette(rainbow(4))`, returned v2 vector contained four colors...What was the reason for that? Regarding for loop, I am just curious about solution...that's all. But, thank you for pointing out my wrong use of _palette_ and valuable simple solution for the question.